# Common JNDI Lookup for multiple stateless session beans with EJB 3.1 and Weblogic 12.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic12c

I am working on ejb 3.1 with weblogic 12.1.2

remote interface code:

```
@Remote
public interface WordInterface{

    public String cities();

}
```

session bean class code:

```
@Stateless(mappedName="wordbean")
public class WordSessionBean  implements WordInterface {

    @Override
    public String cities() {
        return "This is NewYork";
    }
```

Client code :

```
WordInterface obj = (WordInterface) ctx.lookup("wordbean#com.WordSessionBean");
```

The above client Jndi Lookup is mapped to a specific bean name.

This is working fine. 
But i have multiple sessionbeans and remote interfaces with different mappedNames.

How should i configure my Jndi lookup which is common to all SessionBean classes in RealTime.

The client and server classes will be in different jvms

I tried using following statement

WordInterface obj = (WordInterface) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/wordbean");

But giving this error

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'java:comp.env/ejb/wordbean' didn't find subcontext 'java:comp'. Resolved '' [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

How to solve this ?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Comment: @Bruno, as per tutorial i have edited my question with latest answer, please clarify that.

Comment: Have you tried to inject your EJB on the client side? `@EJB(mappedName="wordbean#com.WordInterface")`